# Mono.ZeroConf Windows

Tags: networking, mono, bonjour, zeroconf

Hello i started off with a tutorial from [Mono ZeroConf](http://abock.org/2007/12/23/announcing-monozeroconf)

When my code reahes the line

```
ServiceBrowser browser = new ServiceBrowser ();
```

i get a SystemException

```
System.Exception: No Zeroconf providers could be found or initialized. Necessary daemon may not be running.
```

So how do i run the necessary deamon or provider (on windows)?

Comment: I think you need the system zeroconf (rendezvous or bonjour) service to be running

Comment: well that says the exception, but how do i run the zeroconf daemon

Answer (score 4):

You need to download and install [Bonjour for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999). On completing the setup the deamon should start automatically. Many of the available Mono.Zeroconf binaries are out of date and contain bugs. However, you can download and compile the latest version from [github](https://github.com/mono/Mono.Zeroconf).